# How to uniquely identify a browser on a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have a horizontal portal that caters to different categories.

This portal now needs a Chrome extension that will allow users to follow articles in different categories separately. That is, one user may pick Sports, Movies while another may pick Politics & Fashion.

I am wondering if we can let the user to specify these individual interests without having to create a login. I think this is possible if we can uniquely identify a Chrome browser and assign the interests against this #ID.

It will be great if someone can explain how it can be done.

Comment: why do you want to assign them to the ID of the extension and not directly save the interest in the Extension

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a typical job for a cookie. Just store the category subscriptions in the cookie, that's all there is to it.

Comment: But most of the users delete cookies or doesnt allow them.

Comment: @Vloxxity: I don't think this is a normal situation. Requiring a specific browser went out of fashion with IE6. So, it's probably an company intranet. Even so, if a user decides to delete cookies, then he probably doesn't want other hacks either. Those users will accept that you don't keep their preferences, since that's the natural consequence.